# Sending results of MStest (from XML) to my manager

Tags: .net, logging, webdriver, mstest

I am using Selenum Webdriver using .Net bindings, Selenium Grid, MStest framework, testing our web application.

My manager does not want to have to scan an XML file, which is the output format from MStest logs. He also doesn't want to open the .trx file in Visual Studio (doesn't have VS studio installed).

I want to provide a way for him to easily see the results of automated testing by fetching the info himself, like through a web URL or other method.

I could write a perl script to parse the XML into a webpage. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel. This seems like a really common need.

I already have built in functionality that emails my boss if there is a failure.

**Isn't there some standard way for people to read the results of their tests in a layman readable format?** I am writing this post knowing it may attract a bunch of ads for specific plugins. But what I really want to know is whether there is some tried and true standard method.

My output looks like this:

```
-<UnitTestResult outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" executionId="4554a086-ffc9-48a3-81a3-1c97da18a32f" testId="14f288b2-4758-186e-8101-87acd599e23c" relativeResultsDirectory="4554a086-ffc9-48a3-81a3-1c97da18a32f" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" endTime="2013-05-23T17:58:26.9575999-07:00" startTime="2013-05-23T17:57:51.6000645-07:00" duration="00:00:35.1400076" computerName="myMachineName" testName="mySmokeTest">
  -<Output>
    <StdOut>Hello pappy! System.Environment.MachineName=CCI-SKYN outFilePath is W:\\CCI_SMOKE_TESTS-CCI-SKYN-firefox.csv</StdOut>
  </Output>
</UnitTestResult>
```

And I want my manager to be able to call a web address or open a file and it to look something like this:

```
mySmokeTest
Passed
StartTime:2013-05-23T17:57:51.6000645-07:00
endTime=2013-05-23T17:58:26.9575999-07:00
duration=00:00:35.1400076
```

But I am open to any standard solution that fits the framework I am using.

Comment: I do not know any "standard ways" but if you'll end up implementing your own solution this article could be helpful for you: [Generating HTML reports from TRX using XSLT](http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/27-trx-to-html-using-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

You could apply an XSLT to he xml to display somthing pretty in the brower... 
http://rhysc.blogspot.com/2009/02/mstest-xslt.html

Whip a little script to search the contents of the XML and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful. i am not sure how to call this transform. Can it be called from a URL or command line? I want to avoid having to log into Visual Studio to read the logs. Posted a question on the link you sent, we'll see what reply I get.

Comment: An xlst transform is done client side in the browser. you tell the browser an xml file and xslt transform, and it renders html